# Returning a reference and returning a value

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am not quite sure that I have understood why there is a problem when we return the reference of a local random variable. So let's say that we have this example.

```
int *myFunc() {
  int phantom = 4;
  return &phantom;
}
```

Then the usual argument is that when the function is used, the memory of the variable `phantom` is no longer available after the execution of the code line `int phantom = 4;` so it cannot be returned (at least this is what I have understood so far). On the other hand, for the function,

```
int myFunc() {
  int phantom = 4;
  return phantom;
}
```

the value of the integer variable `phantom` will return. (I see the returning of the value as the dereferencing of an underlying pointer for the variable `phantom`).

What do I miss here?? Why in the first case there is a compilation error and in the second case everything works??

Answer (score 2):

The first doesn't return a reference, it returns a pointer. A pointer to a local variable who will go out of scope once the function ends, leaving you with a stray pointer to a variable that doesn't exist anymore. That's why you get a compiler *warning* (usually not an actual error).

The second code copies the value. The local variable inside the function will never need to be referenced or used once the `return` statement finished.

Comment: @xaxxon Using the correct terminology is important :)

Comment: @xaxxon: Technically a reference is like a non-nullable, const pointer. But they have different semantics and should not be conflated.

I'd say Joachim Pileborg has the correct answer, but it is also worth mentioning that in most simple cases like this, NRVO will kick in and elide the copy. So it's worth just returning by value until you find yourself needing to return a BigHonkingObject that has to be heap-allocated.

Comment: @djrollins no, technically a reference is something that refers to something else.  Like how a pointer refers to a memory address.  A *c++ reference* is more specific.  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reference

Comment: "The second code copies the value. The local variable inside the function will never need to be referenced or used once the return statement finished." Where does it copy the value?? I guess somewhere so that it can be obtained and returned at the return statement...Do you mean that there is an implicit allocation of memory in the heap of a new int object so that the value is somehow accessible?

Comment: Or in other words, in the second scenario, when the function `int myFunc()` is executed, then following your logic, the address of the local variable phantom will be lost, so how the value of it can be returned??? Is there an implicit allocation of memory to a memory path that is accessible?

Comment: when you say copy, do you mean that the command "new" is implicitely used and memory in Heap has been created??

Comment: @noob-mathematician: There is no `new` and no heap usage.

Comment: @xaxxon: What's your point anyway? This is a C++ question with C++ answers, so of course there is a big difference between pointers and references. You even acknowledge this in your comments!

Comment: @ChristianHackl my point is that reading comprehension is about context clues.

Answer (score 0):

You dont miss much. Only that in the first case there will be no compiler error.

> [...] the memory of the variable phantom is no longer available after the execution of the code line int phantom = 4; so it cannot be returned

No, it can be returned and compilers may issue a warning for that but afaik no error. However, you should not!!

Btw, the memory is available, but it is undefined behaviour to access it after the function returned (not after the line `int phantom = 4;`).

In the second case:

> I see the returning of the value as the dereferencing of an underlying pointer for the variable phantom

You are thinking too complicated here. Returning a value from a function may be implemented by using a pointer, but thats an implementation detail. The only thing you have to care about here is that what is returned is the **value**. So no problems in the second case.

Comment: The actual question is this : if the memory of the local variable phantom dissapears then how the value of phantom returns in the second case?? Somehow this value should be stored somewhere in order to be returned at the end of the function... Right?

Comment: @noob-mathematician memory does not disappear. In the second case a copy of the value is returned to the caller. This mechanism has nothing to do with some variable that you might have declared inside the function. You could also have `return 1;`

Comment: @noob-mathematician you may want to read about [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). Maybe this helps to clarify things a bit

Answer (score 0):

The first case

```
int* myFunc()
{
   int phantom = 4;
   return &phantom;  // you are returning the address of phantom
}                    // but phantom will not "exist" outside of myfunc
```

Doesn't work because variable `phantom` is a local variable and it lives only during the execution of `myfunc`. After that, it's gone.

You are returning an address of a variable, that will practically "not exist" any more.

**The rule: never return pointers or references to local variables.**

This is OK:

```
 int myFunc()
 {
    int phantom = 4;
    return phantom;  // you are returning by value;
                     // it doesn't matter where phantom "lives"
 }                  

 int main()
 {
    int x = myFunc(); // the value returned by myFunc will be copied to x
 }
```

Comment: Most people who say that the second is Ok have no idea why it is Ok. And that is the scope of my question. If the first is not OK, why the second is Ok?? In order to return the integer in the second scenario you need to "store" it somewhere, otherwise, following the logic of the first scenario the local variable disappears right before the return statement.

Comment: @noob-mathematician: C++ guarantees that it will work; period. It doesn't matter what mechanism your particular compiler uses to allocate/store/save that value. You only need to know that it does.

Comment: @noob-mathematician: *"Most people who say that the second is Ok have no idea why it is Ok."* - That's quite a stretch! :)

Comment: To get the answer, you need to know assembly and computer architecture a little bit. The return value will be stored inside an register, and then depending on your code moved to a specific memory location( x=myFunc() ---in this case to the location where x is).

Answer (score 0):

> I am not quite sure that I have understood why there is a problem when
>   we return the reference of a local random variable

Because the C++ standard says it is **undefined behaviour** if you use such a function, and you want to avoid undefined behaviour in your program. What your program does should be determined by the rules of the C++ language, not be random.

Note that you return a pointer and not a reference. But it's undefined behaviour in both cases.

> Then the usual argument is that when the function is used, the memory
>   of the variable `phantom` is no longer available after the execution of
>   the code line `int phantom = 4;` so it cannot be returned (at least this
>   is what I have understood so far).

This is an implementation-centric point of view and may *aid* you in understanding the problem.

Nevertheless, it's important to distinguish between the observable behaviour of a program and the compiler's internal tricks to produce that behaviour. You don't even know whether any memory is occupied by a variable anyway. Considering the "as-if" rule and compiler optimisations, the entire function may have been removed, even if the behaviour was defined. That's just one example of what might really happen behind the scenes.

But again, it's undefined behaviour anyway, so anything may happen.

The question is, then, why does the C++ standard not define a behaviour for the case when you return a pointer like this and then try to access the pointee? The answer to that would be that it doesn't make sense. The object named by the local variable `phantom` ends its life when the function returns. So you would have a pointer to something which no longer exists, yet it's still an `int*`, and dereferencing a non-`nullptr` `int*` should yield an `int`. That's a **contradiction**, and the C++ standard just does not bother to resolve such a meaningless situation.

Note how this observation is based on C++ language rules, *not* on compiler-implementation issues.

> Why in the first case there is a compilation error and in the second
>   case everything works??

It's certainly a warning and not an *error*, unless your compiler options are such that every warning is turned into an error. The compiler must not reject the code, because [it's not ill-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296665/why-is-returning-a-reference-to-a-function-local-value-not-a-compile-error).

Still, your compiler tries to be helpful in the first case, because it wants to keep you from creating a program with undefined behaviour.

In the second case, the behaviour is not undefined. Returning by value means that a **copy** is made of the object which you want to return. The copy is made before the original is destroyed, and the caller then receives that copy. That's not meaningless and not a contradiction in any way, so it's safe and defined behaviour.

In the first case, returning by value does not help you, because although the pointer itself *is* safely copied, its contents are what eventually causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: "The object named by the local variable phantom ends its life when the function returns." So it lives until and and including the return statement (hence so does its address). This statement does not satisfy me but I agree that the problem has to do with the rules followed in the very construction of C++.

Answer (score -1):

Try returning the pointer and dereference it to get the value.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int *myFunc()
{

    int number = 4;
    int *phantom = &number;

    return phantom;

}

int main()
{
    cout << myFunc() << endl; //0x....
    cout << *myFunc() << endl; //4
    return 0;
}
```